# How does a motherboard with 2 DDR2-RAM slots support 8GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr2

I have an MSI motherboard: [K9N6PGM2-V2](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6PGM2-V2.html#?div=Detail). This motherboard has 2 DIMMs sockets for DDR2-RAMs. But it's stated in [MSI website](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6PGM2-V2.html#?div=Detail) that it supports up to 8GB RAM

> Main Memory
>
> - Supports Dual Channel DDR2 667/800
>
> - **2 DDR2 DIMMs** (240pin / 1.8V)
>
> - **Supports a maximum memory size up to 8GB**.

How could this be, if the DDR2 cards are of maximum of 2GBs. That means 2x2GB RAM which is 4GB maximum? Can anyone explain to me ?

Comment: Motherboards also sometimes support more memory than what is then possible. For example, the [Asus' P67 line](http://goo.gl/BwXiB) supports 32GB, but I couldn't find anyone that manufactured [16GB DDR3 sticks when it was new, 2 months ago](http://goo.gl/4Xbs4).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

4Gb DDR2 sticks are available(but quite expensive) and there are even bigger server ones.

Comment: @BarsMonster i've flagged for admin

Comment: Up to 8gb on Crucial. :)

Comment: Thanks @BarsMonster, I didn't find 4GB DDR2 sticks in Egypt that's why i expected there are no 4GB DDR2 sticks !

Comment: I apologize if this offtopic, i expected it's a stackoverflow for Hardware questions, if i'm wrong please correct me ...